# C# Ping.Send causing GUI to freeze

Tags: c#, user-interface, ping, freeze

first time using Stackoverflow so i'll try to do my best.

I was making a little app to ping some servers, the issue i'm having is that the GUI of the program locks up while it waits for a response.
This is what I have so far, Button_Click is the "Ping IP" button, ping_box is a textbox that will contain the response time, ip_address is a IP address in the form of a string.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        {
            using (Ping p = new Ping())
            {
                ping_box.Text = (p.Send(ip_address, 1000).RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms\n");

                if (ping_box.Text == "0ms\n")
                {
                    ping_box.Text = "Server is offline or exceeds 1000ms.";
                }
            }
        }
        s.Stop();
    }
```

So in its current state it pings the IP address repeatedly for two seconds and puts the response time into a textbox, during this time the GUI locks up though.
I need to recorrect this as I want the textbox with the response time to update with each ping (if the response time is 500 ms then the textbox should update four times).

I've tried to use Ping.SendAsync but could not get it to work, any pointers or help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You should to use `SendAsync` to keep it off of the UI thread. Post your code using that method so we can help.

Comment: Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx you can find documentation and an example how to use `SendAsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should help...
You can modify it further as per your needs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");
    var pingSender = new Ping();

    pingSender.PingCompleted += PingCompletedCallback;
    pingSender.SendAsync(ip, 1000, waiter);
}

private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user. 
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Ping failed: {0}", e.Error.ToString()), 
                        "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        // Let the main thread resume. 
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }

    DisplayReply(e.Reply);

    // Let the main thread resume.
    ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
}

public void DisplayReply(PingReply reply)
{
    if (reply == null)
        return;

    ping_box.Text = string.Format("Ping status: {0}, RoundTrip time: {1}", 
                                    reply.Status,
                                    reply.RoundtripTime.ToString());

}
```

Comment: After a bit of testing it seems to not like hostnames, so I tried to convert the hostnames to IP addresses using **real_ip = (Dns.GetHostAddresses("websitehere.com")).ToString();** but for some reason it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Ping
>   Allows an application to determine whether a remote computer is
>   accessible over the network.

When you called Ping, your Main Thread (and that is your UI Thread) has been halt and wait for ping respond, that's why your application freeze.

solution: 
You need to put Ping in another Thread

Comment: Or use [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e6kc029(v=vs.110).aspx)